# How to use a jQuery function on mutliple images

Tags: jquery, each

I have a collection of images all with the class of "imgGroup".
For each image there is a div containing two buttons. These divs are assigned a class called "btnActions". My image are displayed from a database.

If I have an unknown amount of images, how can I utilize the jQuery code below on each individual image? Currently when I hover over an image, the "btnActions" divs for all images are displayed (as expected - but not desired).

P.S - This jQuery.each function seems like a solution but my brain is not wrapping around it very well.

Thanks

```
$('.imgGrp').hover(function() {  
    $('.btnActions').css("display", "block");  
});
```

Comment: How do you link each image to its div?

Comment: Please, post your html, the result will depend on that.

Comment: If one of these answers helped you, why dont you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.imgGrp').hover(function() {  
    $('.btnActions', $(this)).css("display", "block");  
});
```

will onnly apply to the ".btnActions" you are hover on.

Comment: Thanks Johannes but this does not seem to be working. I see where you are headed with this and will dig deeper into this approach.

Comment: important thing is the idea of using the 'context'. If you show me your exact html code, I could help you with the js-function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript for this.

```
.imgGrp:hover .btnActions {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan but I am just trying to display/show the btnActions DIV for the image I am hovering over... not all of them

Comment: Then apply the hover to a class attached to a specific image, not the group, since you don't want anything to happen when you hover over the group.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery script will show the item with the class "btnActions" when you are over the item with class "imgGroup". Once you move your mouse the item with class "btnActions" will hide. The window.load part will wait til all your images have loaded before applying the effect.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(".imgGroup").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).find("button").show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).find("button").show();
      }
    );

});
```

Voila good luck let me know how it goes!

PS: you can also make it fade in by replacing regular .show() and .hide() by .show('slow') and .hide('fast').

**UPDATE:**

Here is another method that might work:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(".imgGroup").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $(".hover > .btnActions").show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $(".hover > .btnActions").hide();
      }
    );

});
```

Let me know if they work.

Comment: Thanks Karl but this does the same thing. It shows the btnActions DIV for all images at once. I am just trying to display/show the btnActions DIV for the image I am hovering over.

Comment: I understand better now. I changed the jQuery to search for a button tag within the item you are hovering over to display instead. You can also change "button" to another tag if you are using "input" instead. Try that.

Comment: If you look back at my answer, I also added an alternate method that might work as well.

Comment: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner! $(this).find.
Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Glad it works! Make sure to click the check mark beside my answer! Let me know if I can help with anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Mickormick.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(".imgGroup").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $(".hover > .btnActions").show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $(".hover > .btnActions").hide();
      }
    );

});
```

Comment: You should merge your two answers.